# Minecraft delete mods problem

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I wanted to delete my lom mod (lots of mobs mod) because it is crashing Minecraft, but I can't because it claims Minecraft is running. However, I do not see Minecraft on my screen.

I want to delete my mod without restarting my computer, my restarting doesn't seem to properly work. So I want to close javaw.exe on my task manager but it seems I have alot of javaw.exe and has different type of numbers on it (my first time working with task manager)

Which one do I close?

Comment: Any program that uses Java will have a process called "javaw.exe". Try closing out of the other programs on your computer and the number of processes will go down. 

However, if you have exited Minecraft, you should have no trouble adjusting the mods. What exactly is the problem you're getting?

Comment: there are like **** tons of javaw.exe. And i dont know which is the real one!

Comment: Yes, it says it cant be removed because the program is running

Comment: Its closed. There isnt a minecraft running

Comment: Try right clicking on one of the javaw.exe processes, then clicking "End Process Tree".

Answer (score 3):

Any program that uses Java will have a process called "javaw.exe". Try closing out of the other programs on your computer and the number of processes will go down. Some sample programs that use Java include web browsers, other games, some music players, et cetera.

Your safest bet, unfortunately, is probably to save your work and restart your computer, thus killing all the Java programs at once. Then you should be able to remove the mod. The fact that Minecraft is still considered running despite not being visible on your screen indicates that something has gone wrong in the first place, and you might be seeing computer slowdowns and odd behavior which a restart would clear right up.

Answer (score 0):

How are you trying to delete it?  Minecraft doesn't enforce restrictions on deleting files as far as I know.  The best solution to quitting things you can't see is rebooting the computer, what is your problem with that?

Answer (score -1):

hey just here to help but go to task manager in the processes tab go under background processes and end any running java tasks. This will allow you to delete any mods, forge files or other unneeded files. :D